# "Please provide a valid cache path" error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I duplicated a working laravel app and renamed it to use for another app.  I deleted the vendor folder and run the following commands again:

```
composer self-update

composer-update

npm install

bower install
```

I configured my routes and everything properly however now when I try to run my app in my browser I get the following errors:

> InvalidArgumentException in Compiler.php line 36: Please provide a
>   valid cache path.
>
> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111:
>   file_put_contents(F:\www\example\app\storage\framework/sessions/edf262ee7a2084a923bb967b938f54cb19f6b37d):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have never had this issue before, I do not know what is causing it neither do I know how to fix it, I have googled online for a solution but have found none so far.

Comment: You need to rebuild the storage folders, they are in your .gitignore file so wont be copied when you clone a project (as they are never pushed to the repo)

Answer (score 922):

Try the following:

create these folders under **storage/framework:**

- **`sessions`**
- **`views`**
- **`cache`**

Now it should work

Comment: I combined this with php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:clear and php artisan view:clear from the answer below and then it worked

Comment: You can delete the storage folder manually and run the "php artisan storage:link" command via cmd. Then create folders as suggested above. Better you can keep the previous Storage folder as backup and later copy - paste the framework folder in new Storage path.

Comment: I had exactly this issue and fix worked, was a result of deliberately excluding the entire framework folder from my subversion product due to its constant temporary file changing content.   Then setting up the repro on a new system naturally resulted in these folders not existing.  Thought I'd share...

Comment: git doesn't clone empty folders! I will create a file folder.keeper for those 3 folders.

Comment: Yes, because don't need versioned this folders

Comment: A .gitkeep file in each directory would do the trick to prevent it to happen again

Comment: also make sure to add "data" folder under cache to prevent having the following error "failed to clear cache. make sure you have the appropriate permissions"

Comment: Also make sure that if you changed the 'compiled' config value in `config/view.php` or the environment variable `VIEW_COMPILED_PATH` this directory also exists

Comment: I solve this with this architecture: 

```storage/framework/.gitignore
storage/framework/cache
storage/framework/cache/.gitignore
storage/framework/sessions
storage/framework/sessions/.gitignore
storage/framework/testing
storage/framework/testing/.gitignore
storage/framework/views
storage/framework/views/.gitignore
```

Comment: on my case, i am missing the `views` folder. created it and it worked perfectly. thank you! `[+1]`

Comment: View is the missing folder.I created manually and it worked perfectly. 
thank you!

Comment: you also need the `framework/cache/data` subfolder

Answer (score 77):

Run these command to create required directories:

```
cd storage/
mkdir -p framework/{sessions,views,cache}
chmod -R 775 framework
```

That's it!

Comment: Depending on the group used, it may still be better to use `755`.

Answer (score 63):

Try this:

1. `php artisan cache:clear`
2. `php artisan config:clear`
3. `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I got `[InvalidArgumentException] Please provide a valid cache path`. again

Comment: In my case got a nightmare if run `php artisan cache:clear`!

Comment: LOL... running this command too gives the same error

Comment: Before run this command. create these folders under storage/framework:

**1) sessions
2) views
3) cache**

Answer (score 51):

The cause of this error can be traced from Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php

```
public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $cachePath)
{
    if (! $cachePath) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Please provide a valid cache path.');
    }

    $this->files = $files;
    $this->cachePath = $cachePath;
}
```

The constructor is invoked by BladeCompiler in Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider

```
/**
 * Register the Blade engine implementation.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\View\Engines\EngineResolver  $resolver
 * @return void
 */
public function registerBladeEngine($resolver)
{
    // The Compiler engine requires an instance of the CompilerInterface, which in
    // this case will be the Blade compiler, so we'll first create the compiler
    // instance to pass into the engine so it can compile the views properly.
    $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function () {
        return new BladeCompiler(
            $this->app['files'], $this->app['config']['view.compiled']
        );
    });

    $resolver->register('blade', function () {
        return new CompilerEngine($this->app['blade.compiler']);
    });
}
```

So, tracing back further, the following code:

```
$this->app['config']['view.compiled']
```

is generally located in your /config/view.php, if you use the standard laravel structure.

```
<?php
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Compiled View Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines where all the compiled Blade templates will be
    | stored for your application. Typically, this is within the storage
    | directory. However, as usual, you are free to change this value.
    |
    */
    'compiled' => realpath(storage_path('framework/views')),
];
```

**realpath(...)** returns false, if the path does not exist. Thus, invoking

```
'Please provide a valid cache path.' error.
```

Therefore, to get rid of this error, what you can do is to ensure that

```
storage_path('framework/views')
```

or

```
/storage/framework/views
```

exists :)

Comment: This one solves my issue. I'm creating a Laravel project but a backend only so I don't have anything to display like a view on my root route.

Answer (score 46):

Ensure the below folders in **storage** directory:

- logs
- framework
- framework/cache
- framework/cache/data
- framework/sessions
- framework/testing
- framework/views

Below is a command-line snippet that does for you

```
cd storage
mkdir logs
mkdir framework
mkdir framework/cache && framework/cache/data
mkdir framework/sessions
mkdir framework/testing
mkdir framework/views
chgrp -R www-data ../storage
chown -R www-data ../storage
```

Comment: Or:
```
export STORAGE_PATH='/path/tostorage/dir'
mkdir -p ${STORAGE_PATH}/{logs,framework/{cache/data,sessions,testing,views}}
chgrp -R www-data ${STORAGE_PATH}
chown -R www-data ${STORAGE_PATH}
```

Answer (score 28):

You need to create folders inside "framework". Please Follow these steps:

```
cd storage/
mkdir -p framework/{sessions,views,cache}
```

You also need to set permissions to allow Laravel to write data in this directory.

```
chmod -R 775 framework
chown -R www-data:www-data framework
```

Comment: Can you please explain the command: 
`chown -R www-data:www-data framework`

Comment: The chown command changes user ownership of a folder or file.
command ```chown```
-R means recursive.
www-data:www-data => username:group assigning to framework folder.

You will have complete detail about chown command. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-chown-command-with-examples

Answer (score 27):

You can edit your **readme.md** with instructions to install your laravel app in other environment like this:

````
## Create folders

```
#!terminal

cp .env.example .env && mkdir bootstrap/cache storage storage/framework && cd storage/framework && mkdir sessions views cache

```

## Folder permissions

```
#!terminal

sudo chown :www-data app storage bootstrap -R
sudo chmod 775 app storage bootstrap -R

```

## Install dependencies

```
#!terminal

composer install

```
````

Answer (score 19):

Try the following:

create these folders under storage/framework:

- sessions
- views
- cache/data

if still it does not work then try

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

if get an error of not able to clear cache. Make sure to create a folder data in cache/data

Answer (score 19):

My 2 cents

Remove everything inside storage and then do this:

```
> cd storage/
> mkdir -p framework/{sessions,views,cache}
> chmod -R 755 framework

// This last line depends on your user group settings so 
// it may not be applicable to you.
> chown -R www-data:www-data framework
```

Worked for me =)

Comment: Thanks for updating! Better to learn about 777 being insecure this way than the hard way, right? :-)

Answer (score 13):

1. Start by clearing the cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

2. If it doesn't work, ensure the all the following folders are available

```
logs
framework
framework/cache 
framework/sessions 
framework/views
```

3. If none of the suggestions works, verify that the config file `config/view.php` is present. If not, you can get a copy of this file for the Laravel you're using and copy it to the project config folder.

Answer (score 10):

Check if the following folders exists, if not create these folders.

- storage/framework/cache
- storage/framework/sessions
- storage/framework/testing
- storage/framework/views

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem when I created **framework** folder inside **storage** folder and its subfolders **sessions**, **views** and **cache**.

Go to your cmd or terminal then type your project root path and after that type the following:

```
cd storage
mkdir framework
cd framework
mkdir sessions
mkdir views
mkdir cache
```

Go to your project root path back again and run **composer update**

After that artisan works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

Step 1、Create these folders

- mkdir -p storage/{app,framework,logs}
- mkdir -p storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache}
- chmod -R 777 storage

Step 2、Clear cache/config/view

- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan view:clear

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, give full write access to all users on a system, which is what you are doing here with `chmod -R 777`. THIS IS AN INVITATION TO BE HACKED, as your web server process user can now write there too.

Answer (score 5):

**step 1** : `php artisan storage:link`

**step 2** : create these folders inside storage folder

Ensure the below folders in storage directory:

```
logs
framework
framework/cache 
framework/sessions 
framework/views
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Please run in terminal,

```
   sudo mkdir storage/framework
   sudo mkdir storage/framework/sessions
   sudo mkdir storage/framework/views
   sudo mkdir storage/framework/cache
   sudo mkdir storage/framework/cache/data
```

Now you have to change permission,

```
   sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

Comment: If you want create dynamically, you can also create as, 

 `$paths = ["storage","storage/framework", "storage/framework/sessions", "storage/framework/views", "storage/framework/cache", "storage/framework/cache/data", "storage/logs", "storage/fonts"];`
       ` foreach( $paths  as $path){`
           ` if (!File::isDirectory($path)) { `
                `File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);`
            `}`
        `}`

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, give full write access to all users on a system, which is what you are doing here with `chmod -R 777`. THIS IS AN INVITATION TO BE HACKED, as your web server process user can now write there too.

Answer (score 2):

First create these folders under **storage/framework:**

- **`sessions`**
- **`views`**
- **`cache`**

Now run on terminal

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan view:clear

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Issue on my side(while deploying on localhost): there was views folder missing..
so
if you have don't have the framework folder the you 'll need to add folders.
but if already framework folder exist then make sure all above folders i.e
 1. cache 
 2. session
 3. views

exists in your framework directory.

Answer (score 1):

If this happens on server:

```sh
sudo mkdir logs framework framework/cache framework/sessions framework/views
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to do is replace your laravel project Storage folder to another laravel project Storage folder and you resolve that issue simple!

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by adding this line in my `index.php`:

```
$app['config']['view.compiled'] = "storage/framework/cache";
```

Answer (score -1):

Your storage directory may be missing, or one of its sub-directories. The storage directory must have all the sub-directories that shipped with the Laravel installation.

Answer (score -1):

May be the storage folder doesn't have the app and framework folder and necessary permission. Inside framework folder it contains cache, sessions, testing and views. use following command this will works.

```
Use command line to go to your project root: 
cd {your_project_root_directory}
Now copy past this command as it is: 
cd storage && mkdir app && cd app && mkdir public && cd ../ && mkdir framework && cd framework && mkdir cache && mkdir sessions && mkdir testing && mkdir views && cd ../../ && sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

I hope this will solve your use.

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, give full write access to all users on a system, which is what you are doing here with `chmod -R 777`. THIS IS AN INVITATION TO BE HACKED, as your web server process user can now write there too.

Answer (score -1):

I also had a similar case after copying a project on a production server. The public folder was accessed by Apache via a symbolic link.

For Apache or the PHP service, the path to the project has not changed, thus they used cached file paths that lead to the old project repository.

Restarting Apache and PHP service resolved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the config cache files are all missing in boostrap/cache... so solution to me is `php artisan config:cache` to re-create cache files at boostrap/cache.

Answer (score -5):

Error :'Please provide a valid cache path.' error.

If these type error comes then the solution given below :-

please create data folder inside storage/framework/cache

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide answers that include not just the solution, but at least a few words about how you found this out.