# "Please provide a valid cache path" error after upgrade above 5.2.39

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have strange problem. After upgrading from 5.2.39 to 5.2.40 or 5.2.41 I get `Throw exception if view cache path is empty.`

I cannot revert the change - after upgrade all Composer or Artisan comments fail I guess is related to [the change in Laravel 5.2.40](https://laraver.xyz/projects/Laravel/versions/v5.2.40).

How I can fix this?

A problem like this [was fixed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483837/please-provide-a-valid-cache-path) but the solution doesn't work in my case.

### Dirty fix

Only preemption for future damage. I still cannot fix the damaged app. 
I replaced `laravel/framework": "5.2.*",`with `"laravel/framework": "5.2.39",` to avoid breaking up this and other apps I have built. After the change the `composer update` would not disrupt my app.

Comment: If composer or artisan comments failed then try remove vendor folder then run composer install

Comment: I have tested taht solution. Didn't help. At the other question they just had no cache folders, which made the error to appear. I have the folder in place. This must be some strange compatibility issue within the app itself.

Comment: did you tried using remove bootstrap/cache?

Comment: I just tried. I got `file_put_contents(D:\www\!Buluoge\bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: remove bootstrap/cache then remove "post-install-cmd" part from composer.json and then run composer install

Comment: Nope. Still `file_put_contents(D:\www\!Buluoge\bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483837/please-provide-a-valid-cache-path, there is an answer to it an a work arround too

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem too and I solve it when add the folder views in storage/framework, so just be sure that all folders did exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it like this:

Create these folders under **storage/framework:**

**`sessions
 views
 cache`**

You probably will need to give permission to storage folder again like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```