# Laravel throws 'The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable' error after update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I used 'composer update', which updated a few packages. During the updating process the website still functions. However, after it says 'The compiled services file has been removed', the website doesn't load and instead says:

```
Exception in ProviderRepository.php line 190:
The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.
```

The weirdest thing is, when I run 'composer update' again, the website starts to work again, until the compiled services file is removed, at which point it throws the same error again. I have already tried the usual things that should be done when this error appears (chown -R everything to the right user/group and chmod all the files and folders 664 and 775 respectively).

I don't know what to do anymore, as the error doesn't seem 'correct'..

Comment: I forgot to say that 'composer update' updated the laravel framework as well, from 5.4.18 to 5.4.21

Comment: in my case `mkdir -p bootstrap/cache/ && sudo chown -R user bootstrap/cache/`

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Try this after you have run the composer update:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: A warning is appropriate here. Before running this on production stop and ask yourself if you really want top wipe out your cache. Otherwise, you might end up crippling your app like it happened to me.

Comment: Not working? i dont have have a cache folder inside bootstrap folder

Comment: Also, if this solution doesn't work straight away - check if you have something like OPCache running you may have to restart your PHP-FPM / clear your OPCache cache. :)

Answer (score 36):

On your Laravel directory file, run:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache/
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure 777'ing any folder on a web server isn't such a good idea security-wise. Besides, 775 should and has worked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. 775 has worked **in the past**. At the moment I still have the same problem, as I stated in the original post, I already tried 775'ing and 664'ing everything. The problem is exactly that: I fix what the error says should be fixed, but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Must be `sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap` then only runs fine.

Comment: Useless. NEVER give 777 permission to anything. And NEVER leave "answers" like this.

Answer (score 20):

The  best way to resolve this error is:

1. Open your project folder
2. Move to the `bootstrap` directory
3. Create an empty folder named as `cache`
4. Then do PHP `artisan cache:clear`

This will work for sure

Comment: This solved it for me. I just created a new cache folder. Thanks!

Comment: Did'n't work for me. Threw an InvalidArgumentException: "Please provide a valid cache path."

Answer (score 8):

> **Short version**: If uploading using something like **AWS eb cli** Verify if *bootstrap/cache* folder (not talking about its contents) is being deployed.

**Some background behind my answer**

> I am using Amazon Web Services' Elastic Beanstalk to host my Laravel project. As I just started using Laravel I do not have much idea about its functioning. Two days back My new deployments were all crashing midway with OP's error message.

Earlier that day, I realised that I was not using

```
 php artisan config:cache
```

to cache configurations to make things faster. And I added the same in **composer.json**'s "*post-install-cmd*" and "*post-update-cmd*" clauses.

 And I also added statement in **.ebignore** file to not upload the content of */bootstrap/cache* (as its content is environment dependent **a.k.a** my localhost configurations have no meaning on my production server)


And *facepalm* I did not realise that this will stop the *bootstrap/cache* folder from being uploaded (as Like git, eb cli ignores empty folders).

So, when I started to deploy at night The deployments were meant to crash.


So, now I have just placed empty-placeholder (say) **.gitkeep** file in *bootstrap/cache*. And deployments are working once again :)

(Though the problem was so simple I realised the reason after ssh-ing and digging an EBS EC2 instance for some sweet sleep hours ~.~ )

Comment: It would be very kind of you if you can tell me why you **downvoted** my answer. Because as much as I can see, it solves a **specific** occurrence of the asked problem.

Comment: Sometimes php artisan optimize especially working with node.

Answer (score 6):

For me, I manually created the cache folder inside bootstrap.

Comment: Me too, just delete the current cache folder and recreate it, then problem will be fixed

Comment: That is an easy way to fix this prob. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this too after you have run the composer update:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

Im using cmder on windows 10 in non elevated mode (Non-Admin).
command php artisan cache:clear did not work for me.
The folder bootstrap/cache did not exist.
I created the folder and removed readonly from both bootstrap and bootstrap/cache folder.
Both composer install and composer update are working now.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

hopefully, this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

- First make sure `bootstrap/cache` dir is exist if not create a new one
  `mkdir -p bootstrap/cache/`
- Then run `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

it work for me run in project folder

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
```

than run

```
 composer update
```

than run

```
 cache:clear
```

Comment: it's not bootstrap/cashe but bootstrap/cache

Comment: You shouldn't advice to add chmod 777 to a directory. This is a major security flaw. That way anyone could read, write and execute files in that folder. You can test the security of a given chmod here: https://chmod-calculator.com/

Answer (score 1):

Simple. There are applications that can block the directory. Like google drive synchronizer, One driver synchronizer, or any other application that is using windows explorer.

Delete cache folder. Create this again.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create these five folders to be able to run artisan again.

```
mkdir bootstrap/cache
mkdir storage/framework
mkdir storage/framework/cache
mkdir storage/framework/views
mkdir storage/framework/sessions
```

Answer was found in this related question:
["Please provide a valid cache path" error in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483837/please-provide-a-valid-cache-path-error-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following commands in your project root directory

```
composer update
```

then do

```
composer dumpautoload
```

this will avoid the necessity of messing with cache files 
which may lead to whole new sort of issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine what I got done wrong with that before  and no games around with  that cashclearings had sense. But as it claims there was no 'cache' folder inside /bootstrapp . Had to have create it manually. Now it all rocks ok again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've found out that the `bootstrap/cache` is missing in my project during a fresh clone.

Re-adding the cache directory manually solved my issue.

Then running `composer install` now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**OS: Linux Ubuntu**

If you are using Docker, maybe try this:

```
services:
php:
    restart: always
    container_name: app-php
    user: 'www-data:www-data'
volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html # synchronous
```

And Open Terminal

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER <your_project>
```

Now try this:

```
docker exec -it <your_container_name> /bin/bash
chown -R www-data:www-data bootstrap/
chown -R www-data:www-data storage/

ls -l # You are see folders/files USER/GROUP
php artisan cache:clear # success
php artisan route:clear # success
composer dump-autoload # success
```

Answer (score 0):

If if the top answers fail, then do the following;

```
//cd to your project directory (or just before it), then 
sudo chown -Rv root:$USER .
sudo chmod -Rv g+rw .
```

This will give proper rights to the current user (which is recommended NOT to be root while executing composer).

Answer (score -1):

If a web server (e.g. **Apache** or **Nginx**) is being used as a front-end the solution is to make the directory `bootstrap/cache` owned  by web server group. For **Nginx**:

```
 $ sudo chgrp -R nginx bootstrap/cache
```