# In PackageManifest.php line 177:

Tags: laravel, composer-php

In PackageManifest.php line 177:
The C:\system\bootstrap\cache directory must be present and writable.

Im trying update the lasting composer, and doing php artisan cache:clear
using windows 10

Comment: This is a known bug, you should create the folder(s) manually: https://vander.host/knowledgebase/software-development/how-to-resolve-quotbootstrapcache-directory-must-be-present-and-writablequot-and-quotplease-provide-a-valid-cache-pathquot-errors-whilst-doing-composer-install-for-a-laravel-app/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel throws 'The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable' error after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718391/laravel-throws-the-bootstrap-cache-directory-must-be-present-and-writable-erro)

Answer (score 1):

Delete manually the cache folder from bootstrap folder and create it again manually via New Folder command on Windows.

I solved the same issue doing this thing.