# laravel bootstrap/cache write permission

Tags: laravel, windows, xampp

I want to start working with laravel once more. But I seem to be running into a issue with the write/read settings of my windows 11 machine.

My standard folder setting of windows 11 is read only.

But when I try to launch the **php artisan serve**. I get the following error.

```
The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.
```

I tryed the obvious solutions

1. Right click and change permission -> it cycles back as soon as I leave the window.
2. Look if I am logged in as admin -> I am.
3. Change the advanced security settings -> I am the owner and have full access.
4. Reinstall my hole machine (yes I know drastic)

I hope there is someone who has encountered the same issue and maybe has a solution.

Comment: There's one more thing to try: inside your `bootstrap` directory, is there a `cache` subdirectory?

Comment: Yes there is. But I can not change the read write permission

Comment: Maybe this can help you to solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59299226