# Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please provide a valid cache path

Tags: laravel-5

i  got a laravel project from bitbucket with some missing folder like vendor and storage folder but after i did composer update and the i found that vendor folder was downloaded and other useful dependencies but the storage folder was still empty
and when i run the project i get this error

```html
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis>php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Tue Mar  5 17:10:44 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please provide a valid cache path. in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php(141): Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem), false)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(776): Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider->Illuminate\View\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('blade.compiler', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php on line 36
[Tue Mar  5 17:10:45 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please provide a valid cache path. in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php(141): Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem), false)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(776): Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider->Illuminate\View\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('blade.compiler', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php on line 36
[Tue Mar  5 17:11:08 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please provide a valid cache path. in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php(141): Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem), false)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(776): Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider->Illuminate\View\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('blade.compiler', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php on line 36
[Tue Mar  5 17:11:08 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please provide a valid cache path. in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php(141): Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem), false)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(776): Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider->Illuminate\View\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('blade.compiler', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\genesis\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php on line 36
```

so i am wondering how to download all the missing files from the official laravel project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create followings folder into storage folder :-

```
app

framework 
----> cache
----> sessions
----> views

logs
```

Follow this threat [Please provide a valid cache path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38483837/5928015) to get in-depth knowledge about it.

I hope this will resolve the **Please provide a valid cache path.** issue

Comment: i got **500** status error with the _Whoops, something went wrong on our servers._

Comment: Did you followed the post as i said ? run composer commands to clear cache

Comment: `php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan config:clear`
`composer dump-autoload`
`composer update` run these commands

Comment: Yes i did everything

Comment: So when you run this `php artisan serve` you're still getting same error as you've mentioned in your question is that right ?

Comment: Please check logs created in storage folder see what does it says and turn on debug in .env file `APP_DEBUG=true` to see what exactly this problem is .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create followings folder into storage folder:

- framework
- cache
- sessions
- views

It worked for me.