# Please provide a valid cache path Laravel deployment to GCP¨

Tags: laravel, caching, google-cloud-platform

I got this error when I'm trying to deploy my laravel project to GCP.
I deploy the same project in Heoku I don't have any problem and the project.
Step #1: [29-Aug-2020 20:37:05 UTC] [2020-08-29 20:37:05] local.ERROR: Please provide a valid cache path. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Please provide a valid cache path. at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Compiler.php:36)

My composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
        "bitfumes/laravel-multiauth": "^3.0",
        "bodunde/geocoder": "^1.2",
        "consoletvs/charts": "6.*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "fx3costa/laravelchartjs": "^2.7",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "spatie/geocoder": "^3.5",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39179261/6907339) solution.

Comment: Thank you @rkg. Let me check it.

Comment: I try these suggestions I deploy the app. Now I get the sma eror in production mode. How can I fix it on gcloud. The application is run correctly in locale