# Laravel 8 on App Engine: "Please provide a valid cache path"

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I upgraded a Laravel project from version 7 to 8. When I attempt to deploy it on App Engine, it fails saying "Please provide a valid cache path":

```
Updating service [***]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build [***] status: FAILURE
Error type: UNKNOWN

[...]

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In Compiler.php line 36:

  Please provide a valid cache path.
```

Part of my composer.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets --ansi"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "@php artisan ide-helper:generate",
        "@php artisan ide-helper:meta"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "composer dump-autoload",
        "php artisan config:clear",
        "php artisan cache:clear",
        "php artisan view:clear",
        "php artisan cache:clear",
        "php artisan optimize:clear"
    ]
```

A snippet from app.yaml:

```
env_variables:
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  APP_SERVICES_CACHE: /tmp/services.php
  APP_PACKAGES_CACHE: /tmp/packages.php
  APP_CONFIG_CACHE: /tmp/config.php
  APP_ROUTES_CACHE: /tmp/routes.php
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
```

I do have `/storage/framework/views` folder along with the other standard folders under `/storage` as well as `bootstrap/cache`.

If I remove this line from composer.json (under "post-autoload-dump"):

```
"@php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets --ansi"
```

I am able to deploy the app but it fails on pages that use Livewire components with the following error:

```
The /workspace/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable. (View: /workspace/resources/views/users/edit.blade.php)
ErrorException
in /workspace/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireComponentsFinder.php (line 58)
in /workspace/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/CompilerEngine.php -> handleViewException (line 41)
in /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php -> handleViewException (line 60)
in /workspace/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireViewCompilerEngine.php -> evaluatePath (line 36)
in /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php -> evaluatePath (line 61)
in /workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php -> get (line 139)
```

This happens even though I added the following line to `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->useStoragePath(env('APP_STORAGE', base_path() . '/storage'));
```

following the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard#set_up_database_sessions).

Prior to upgrading Laravel, I had no problems deploying the app on App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really annoying error. It happened every now and then and I still haven't found a fix. I'm sure that there is something weird happening in Cloud Build, I just don't know what. Anyone have any ideas other that the mentioned above please share.

---

**Edit**

I believe the issue lies complied views path as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50133930/10361213)

Now, setting `VIEW_COMPILED_PATH` to `/tmp` is necessary for the app to run BUT, the error occurs during build. During build, the compiled views cache path is read not from `app.yaml`  but from the `config/view.php` or maybe `.env` where the value usually is `realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))`. Now, that is absolutely fine under normal circumstances. The last piece of the puzzle is `gcloud app deploy` which will for some reason neglect to deploy empty directories or directories with only .gitignore in them, hence, `storage/framework/views` will not be deployed and during build the error will occur.

**Possible fixes:**

1. Add some random file (other than `.gitignore`) in 'storage/framework/views' before deploying to make sure the directory is available during build.
2. Change the default value in `config/views` to a directory that is present during build.

Any other way to ensure that `storage/framework/views` is not ignored (present during build) should do.

Comment: Point 1 is the solution for me! You saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My working solution was to edit `config/view.php`:

```php
   'compiled' => env(
        'VIEW_COMPILED_PATH',
        isset($_SERVER['GAE_SERVICE']) ?
            '/tmp'
            : realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))
    ),
```

This will make sure that the default location for compiled views when the app is running on GAE machine is located to `/tmp` directory instead of `storage/framework/views`.

Comment: I like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update the Livewire dependency.

Before:

```
"livewire/livewire": "^1.1",
```

After:

```
"livewire/livewire": "^2.1",
```

Any version beginning with 2.0 seems to work.