# "InvalidArgumentException" Please provide valid cache path in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

After leaving a project for a week and returning (without changing anything) my `php artisan` stopped working. This is only the case for this particular project, since `php artisan` works fine in other projects. When I want to run artisan commands I am getting a

`[InvalidArgumentException] Please provide valid cache path`:

```
PS C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de> php artisan serve

   InvalidArgumentException 

  Please provide a valid cache path.

  at C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php:36
     32▕      */
     33▕     public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $cachePath)
     34▕     {
     35▕         if (! $cachePath) {
  ➜  36▕             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Please provide a valid cache path.');
     37▕         }
     38▕
     39▕         $this->files = $files;
     40▕         $this->cachePath = $cachePath;

  1   C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php:88
      Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler::__construct(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem))

  2   C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:869
      Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::Illuminate\View\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483837/please-provide-a-valid-cache-path-error-in-laravel) proposes to create 3 folders inside `storage\framework` dir:

- sessions
- views
- cache

but I already have those:

[image]

Deleting those folders and creating them new does not help.

What can I do?

**Edit:**

Deleting `vendor` folder and running `composer install` produces the same `exception` at step `@php artisan package:discover --ansi`:

```
PS C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de> composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Package operations: 111 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.23.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.10.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.1.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.23.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.23.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v5.3.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.23.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.23.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/string (v5.3.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/container (1.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.23.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v2.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/console (v5.3.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/log (2.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing monolog/monolog (2.3.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.5.6): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.8.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing graham-campbell/result-type (v1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.3.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v5.3.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/routing (v5.3.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/process (v5.3.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.23.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.23.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/mime (v5.3.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v5.3.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v2.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v5.3.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/error-handler (v5.3.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v5.3.9): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/finder (v5.3.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.23.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.25): Extracting archive
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php81 (v1.23.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing ramsey/collection (1.2.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing brick/math (0.9.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (4.2.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing opis/closure (3.6.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v2.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/translation (v5.3.9): Extracting archive
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (2.53.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.8.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.1.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing nette/utils (v3.2.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing nette/schema (v1.2.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/config (v1.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing league/commonmark (2.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/serializable-closure (v1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/framework (v8.62.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing facade/flare-client-php (1.9.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing facade/ignition (2.14.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing fakerphp/faker (v1.16.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing asm89/stack-cors (v2.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing fruitcake/laravel-cors (v2.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/http-client (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.4.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.3.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/sail (v1.11.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/sanctum (v2.11.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.13.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.10.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing laravel/tinker (v2.6.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing mockery/mockery (1.4.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing filp/whoops (2.14.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing nunomaduro/collision (v5.10.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (2.2.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.5.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.2.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/version (3.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/type (2.3.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/resource-operations (3.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (4.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/object-reflector (2.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (4.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (5.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (4.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/environment (5.1.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/diff (4.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (4.0.6): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit (1.0.8): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/cli-parser (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (5.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (2.0.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-invoker (3.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (3.0.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.2.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/lines-of-code (1.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/complexity (2.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (2.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (9.2.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (1.14.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phar-io/version (3.1.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (2.0.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.10.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (9.5.10): Extracting archive
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   InvalidArgumentException

  Please provide a valid cache path.

  at C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php:36
     32▕      */
     33▕     public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $cachePath)
     34▕     {
     35▕         if (! $cachePath) {
  ➜  36▕             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Please provide a valid cache path.');
     37▕         }
     38▕
     39▕         $this->files = $files;
     40▕         $this->cachePath = $cachePath;

  1   C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php:88
      Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler::__construct(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem))

  2   C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:873
      Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::Illuminate\View\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried updating composer?

Comment: @ArjanShrestha Yes, with the exact same result.

Comment: maybe try deleting vendor folder then composer install

Comment: @ArjanShrestha I ran the command but it ends with the same `exception` when `composer` processes(?) `php artisan`. See the **Edit** section.

Comment: Check if your laravel version supports your current php version

Comment: I'm using `php 8` with `Laravel 8` so it should. I tried `php 7.3` but it produced the same `exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel needs to have a caching directory in order to store the compiled blade templates.

The `path` is defined in `config.view` file as follows:

```php
    'compiled' => env(
        'VIEW_COMPILED_PATH',
        realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))
    ),
```

As you might have noticed, Laravel looks at the `VIEW_COMPILED_PATH` env variable first (if any), if it doesn't exist, then it falls back to `storage/framework/views`.

If Laravel (for any reason) can't get the correct path, then it's going to throw an `InvalidArgumentException` (check it out framework [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/277c2fbd0cebd2cb194807654d870f4040e288c0/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Compiler.php#L36)).

For some reason, the `compiled` path is wrong in your project.

It could be that the `VIEW_COMPILED_PATH` env variable was set to an empty/null value:

```
VIEW_COMPILED_PATH=''

OR

VIEW_COMPILED_PATH=
```

More specifically, the `compiled` entry returns an empty/null value, track it down and check out the returned value.

If the value is correct, then something else (such as Middleware) might have modified it.

**But why composer fails**?

When you run `composer install/update` laravel uses composer script `post-autoload-dump` to run `php artisan package:discover` command.

The `php artisan package:discover` command is going to rebuild the cached package manifest, therefore it hits the compiled views in order to clear them.

To solve the issue, you need to know why the `config.view.compiled` entry returns an invalid value.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your thorough explanation. I have no idea how that could've happened since I did not manually touch the `env variable`. I think I'll recreate the foundation of the project and copy the components.

Comment: IMO, you should track it down, don't create a new foundation; Software development is a learning process, spend some time, debug it and see why it's doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Just run these commands and check.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```